# Javascript regex matches url against root domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a URL with a regex pattern. But I'm stuck because of some strange behaviour (at least, strange to me).

When I run the following code:

```
var url = '/home/123';

var regex = new RegExp("/", "g");
if(url.match(regex)) {
    console.log('aaa');
} else {
    console.log('bbb');
}
```

Then I expect that the `url` doesn't match with the regex `/`. But it does.
I need a regex that doesn't match`/` against `/home/123`.

So my questions are, why does this match? And how can I get the desired result?

Comment: because the forward slash is present in your input.

Comment: Do you want to use anchors: `var regex = new RegExp("^/$", "g");`?

Comment: your regex boils down to `url.indexOf('/') != -1`: "does this string contain a `/`?" - Yes, it does.

Comment: "I need a regex that doesn't match / against /home/123." could you explain me why?

Comment: Oh damn, I forgot about `^` and `$`. That was what I needed to  add. Now `/` doesn't match against `/home/123`.

Comment: this `^(?!/)` will also work. You need to explain your needs inorder to get the output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string matches because part of it contains your regular expression. If you want an exact match, you have to anchor your regular expression

```js
var url = '/home/123';

var regex = new RegExp("^/$", "g");
if(url.match(regex)) {
    console.log('aaa');
} else {
    console.log('bbb');
}
```